# Why is Reduce closing out before it finishes looping through the entire array that is passed in?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to loop through the given array and check that there are no repeated names. If there are, add a number next to the repeated file name. This is my code:

```
const renameFiles = (arr) => {
 let n = 1;
 return arr.reduce((accum, element) => {
  if (!accum.includes(element)) accum.push(element);
  else {
   element = `${element}(${n})`;
   n++;
   if (!accum.includes(element)) accum.push(element);
  }

 return accum;
 }, []);
}
```

When given:

```
renameFiles([
    'a(1)',
    'a(6)',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
    'a',
  ]);
```

I only get

```
[ 'a(1)', 'a(6)', 'a', 'a(2)', 'a(3)', 'a(4)', 'a(5)', 'a(7)', 'a(8)', 'a(9)' ]
```

instead of:

```
[ 'a(1)', 'a(6)', 'a', 'a(2)', 'a(3)', 'a(4)', 'a(5)', 'a(7)', 'a(8)', 'a(9)', 'a(10)', 'a(11)' ].
```

I am not sure why it is not finishing looping through the last two elements in the array.

Comment: Your logic seems off. You're pushing if the `includes` fails, but then you're doing seemingly the same check again in the `else`, but the else won't have been entered in the first place if `includes` returned false, so that second check will fail and nothing will be pushed. It's not a problem with `reduce`. You aren't `push`ing in all cases.

Comment: Don't know why you expect `'a(10)', 'a(11)'`. There are only 10 `a`s in the array. The first one gets no number, the second one gets `a(1)`, so the last one gets `a(9)`.

Comment: I only see 12 elements in your array, not sure why you are expecting 14 values in your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element with the added number is still found in the `accum`, you just drop it instead of trying again with an incremented number. So the two `a`s that would have been converted to `a(1)` and `a(6)` are removed from the output. You can use

```
function renameFiles(arr) {
  let n = 1;
  return arr.reduce((accum, element) => {
    let suffix = "";
    while (accum.includes(element+suffix)) {
      suffix = "(" + n + ")";
      n++;
    }
    accum.push(element+suffix);
    return accum;
  }, []);
}
```